# Is $x^x$ an exponential function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I know that functions of the form $c^x$ are called exponential when $c$ is a constant.

How about the function $x^x$? It seems somewhere in between exponential and double exponential to me. Is there a good way to describe it?

Comment: You can describe its rate of growth as *superexponential* (*i.e.* faster than exponential).

Comment: I've been referring to functions having the form $ \ f(x)^{g(x)} \ $ as "generalized exponential functions" in teaching courses, for lack of a better name.  I can't say I've run across a commonly-used term for these...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding "describing the function": note that
$$
x^x = e^{x \ln x}
$$
So indeed, we may state that (asymptotically) $e^x\leq x^x \leq e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not an exponential function. A function is called exponential if $f(x) = a^x$ where
$a > 0$ ,$a \ne 1$, and $a$ is constant.

Comment: Is there a good way to describe its growth?

Comment: @E-theory Would you please be so kind to define a square?

Comment: @E-theory So won't call $x\mapsto\left(\frac12\right)^x$ an exponential map?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, instead I would like to ask how do you call $x\mapsto2^{\sin(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the fundamental operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation one may ask what result is achieved if one applies one of those operation to a number itself.  To add a number to itself is called doubling, to subtract a number from itself is nameless since it yields always zero, to multiply a number by itself is called squaring, to divide a number by itself remains nameless since it yields one (except $0/0$). For doubling and squaring there are numerous practical reasons.

A number powered to itself is practically useless, one may call it auto-exponentiation or a self-power, but nobody cares.

Edit (to explain the naming): one may consider $x\cdot x$ as a product, it's also $x^2$, that is, a square.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to find a name for $x^x$?  It may be considered to be a power or an exponentiation as $x\cdot x=x^2$ may be considered as a product or as a power.

Comment: Why was the answer downvoted?

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote sometimes. I thought it was an interesting approach.

Comment: I think the downvote might have been because of the comment `practically useless`. There is rather a lot of research into `power towers` for something that is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about this, but I think it would be a 2nd tetration of x. Whether this works like an exponential function, I'm not certain about, but it is commonly referred to as "*iterated exponentiation*", and looks to have similar properties.

Here's the Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: Also, why the downvote - if there is anything wrong please let me know.