# Name and derivative of function $x^x$

Tags: calculus

Name and derivative of function $x^x$

Power functions have base variable, but exponent fixed.

Exponential functions have base fixed, but exponent variable.

I can't find the function in title on derivatives tables.

Comment: Cf the related post 
[Is $x^x$ an exponential function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676641/316749)

Comment: Is there anything which might be improvable which prevents you from accepting one of the given answers?

Answer (score 3):

According to [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) functions of the type

> $$a\uparrow\uparrow k\equiv \underbrace{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{a}}}}}}_{k}$$

are called power towers of $k$-th order also known as $k$-th tetration.

> Therefore the function $f(x)=x^x$ could be called "power tower of order $2$" $($look [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/x-x-does-this-function-have-a-name.70230/#post-519628)$)$.

Since it is not a that common function it would suprise me to find the derivative of this function in a standard table of differentiation. However, it is not hard to find the derivative of $f(x)$ by hand. Just consider that

$$x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}$$

and now by applying the rule for the derivative of an exponential combined with the chain rule we get

$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} x^x&=\frac d{dx} e^{x\ln(x)}\\
&=e^{x\ln(x)}\cdot(x\ln(x))'\\
&=e^{x\ln(x)}\cdot(\ln(x)+1)\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\therefore~ \frac d{dx} x^x=(\ln(x)+1)x^x$$

---

Furhtermore note that $x^x$ does not posses an elementery anti-derivative but the definite integral from $0$ to $1$ can be evaluated in a closed-form known as ["Sophomore's Dream"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the name for $x^x$, but dervitate this function
$f'(x)=f(x)(\ln f(x))'=x^x(x\ln x)'=x^x(\ln x+1)$

Comment: In fact - I doubt it has a universally recognized name. At least, not one that is widely used.

Comment: If you really want a snappy name the second tetration of x is probably the best choice, but that's not really better than "x to the power of x".